# How would I modify this code so that it prints the output of the path it takes to get from point A to B

Tags: c, printing, path

This code answers the question: Given a 2 dimensional matrix where some of the elements are filled with 1 and rest of the elements
are filled. Here X means you cannot traverse to that particular points. From a cell you can either traverse to left, right, up or down. Given two points in the matrix find the shortest path between these points.

I need help implementing a way to print the path between the two points, ex (1,3) -> (1,4), etc. Please help

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>

    char arr[5][5]={    {'1','1','1','1','1'},
                {'1','S','X','1','1'},
                {'1','1','1','1','1'},
                {'X','1','1','E','1'},
                {'1','1','1','1','X'}   };
  int minimum[20];
  int ind=0;

  void addToMin(int len)
  {
     minimum[ind++]=len;
  }

  int IsInPath(int (*path)[5],int r,int c)
  {
     if(path[r][c]==0)   return 0;
    else    return 1;


  }

  int isValid(int r,int c)
  {
      if((r>=0 && r<=4) && (c>=0 && c<=4))
          return 1;
      else
          return 0;
  }


  void findMin(int (*path)[5],int len,int r,int c)
  {
      int path2[5][5];
      int i,j;

      for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
          for(j=0;j<;5;j++)
              path2[i][j]=0;

      if(arr[r][c]=='E')
      {
          addToMin(len);
      }
      else if(arr[r][c]=='X' || (arr[r][c]=='1' && IsInPath(path,r,c)))
      {
          return;
      }
      else if((arr[r][c]=='1' && !IsInPath(path,r,c)) || arr[r][c]=='S')
      {
          for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
              for(j=0;j<;5;j++)
                  path2[i][j]=path[i][j];

          path2[r][c]=1;
          len++;
          if(isValid(r,c-1))         
     findMin(path2,len,r,c-1);

          if(isValid(r-1,c))         
     findMin(path2,len,r-1,c);

          if(isValid(r,c+1))         
     findMin(path2,len,r,c+1);

          if(isValid(r+1,c))          
      findMin(path2,len,r+1,c);

      }
  }

  int main()
  {
      int i,j,flag=0,min=9999;
      int path[5][5];

      for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
          for(j=0;j<;5;j++)
              path[i][j]=0;

      for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
      {

          for(j=0;j<;5;j++)
          {
              if(arr[i][j]=='S')
              {
                  findMin(path,0,i,j);
                  flag=1;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if(flag==1) break;
      }

      for(i=0;i<ind;i++)
      {        
           if(minimum[i]<min)
                min=minimum[i];
      }

      printf("Minimum Distance =%d",min);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: use an array of x/y pairs or a list to record the path. increment index on the way forward and decrement it before return (or add/remove last element from the list). print the contents when reach the endpoint. You will get a few different paths.

Answer (score 0):

regarding Your question: *I need help implementing a way to print the path between the two points.*

The comment by @Serge gives an excellent method of tracing the path from start to finish, with out also displaying any steps that were not kept.  Here is a repeat of that comment:

```
use an array of x/y pairs or a list to record the path. 
increment index on the way forward and decrement it before return (or add/remove last element from the list). 
print the contents when reach the endpoint. 
You will get a few different paths.
```

regarding statements like:

```
for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
```

the `for()` statement has 3 parameters separated via semicolons, not 4 parameters.  Therefore, the semicolon between the `i<` and `5` should not be there.

There are several such syntax errors in the posted code.

The posted code contains the 'magic' number 5, buried all through the code.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest:

```
 #define MAX_ROWS 5
 #define MAX_COLS 5
```

Then using those names throughout the code.

regarding:

```
int i,j,flag=0,min=9999;
```

and

```
if(path[r][c]==0)   return 0;
else    return 1;
```

Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  I.E.

```
int i;
int j;
int flag=0;
int min=9999;
```

and

```
if( path[r][c]==0 )   
    return 0;
else 
    return 1;
```

or even:

```
return ( path[r][c] == 0 )? 0 : 1;
```

regarding:

```
int path[5][5];

  for(i=0;i<;5;i++)
      for(j=0;j<;5;j++)
          path[i][j]=0;
```

This can be reduced to:

```
int path[5][5] = {0};
```

regarding:

```
int (*path)[5]
```

That expression/parameter might work when a parameter is a pointer to a pointer, as when working with a linked list, but is not correct for this problem.  Suggest:

```
int path[][5]
```

as the main thing the compiler needs to know is the length of each row in the matrix.

For ease of readability and understanding:

1. Please consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.
2. insert an appropriate space:  inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after semicolons, after commas, around C operators.
3. separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.
4. separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines. Be consistent.
5. The compiler can read code those formatting is very 'messed up'.  However, us humans work best with uniform, clean formatting of code.

regarding:

```
char arr[5][5]={    {'1','1','1','1','1'},
            {'1','S','X','1','1'},
            {'1','1','1','1','1'},
            {'X','1','1','E','1'},
            {'1','1','1','1','X'}   };
```

In C, the compiler can determine the size of such data elements so, unless there is a very good reason to declare the sizes yourself, much better to let the compiler do it.  Suggest:

```
char arr[][] =
{    
    { '1','1','1','1','1' },
    { '1','S','X','1','1' },
    { '1','1','1','1','1' },
    { 'X','1','1','E','1' },
    { '1','1','1','1','X' }   
};
```

Please explain the meaning of `S`, `E`, and `X` as their meaning is not clear from your question, nor easily derived from the posted code.

it is good coding/design practice to limit the scope of variables.  Therefore statements like:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
```

are much better written as:

```
for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
```

also, since indexes like 'i' will never be <0,  much better to use `size_t`, as in:

```
for( size_t i=0; i<5; i++ )
```